# Couldn't overcome same object error when working with list of dictionaries/json in Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, object

I referred to earlier solutions asking to create new dict as it was having reference.
Here is my code

```
class Block():
    def __init__(self):
        self.JSONOutput = []
    return

    def Obs(self, ObsData):
      JSONStructure = json.load(some json structure)
      for key in ObsData.keys():
         if 'Observation' in key:
             ObsData = ObsData[key]
             new_dict = {}
             new_dict.update(JSONStructure)
             new_dict['fullUrl'] = ObsData['fullUrl']
             temp_dict = {}
             temp_dict.update(new_dict)
             temp_dict['resource']['id'] = ObsData['ObsId']
             self.JSONOutput.append(temp_dict)
      return

d_ip = {}
d_ip['Observation1']={'fullUrl':'123', 'ObsId': 'SPOBS001'}
d_ip['Observation2']={'fullUrl':'456', 'ObsId': 'SPOBS002'}
d_ip['Observation3']={'fullUrl':'789', 'ObsId': 'SPOBS003'}

C = Block()
C.Obs(d_ip)
```

When reviewed the results

`C.JSONOutput[0]['fullUrl'], C.JSONOutput[0]['resource']['id']`

('123', 'SPOBS003')

`C.JSONOutput[1]['fullUrl'], C.JSONOutput[1]['resource']['id']`

('456', 'SPOBS003')

`C.JSONOutput[2]['fullUrl'], C.JSONOutput[2]['resource']['id']`

('789', 'SPOBS003')

**Note:

1. I have two new dictionary in code just to avoid the same key error but still its the case,  Ideally I would like to have each obsid spread across.
2. I also do have further fields which require amendment deep down json structure.

Hoping for solution in all sub level.

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every `temp_dict['resource']` is a reference to `JSONStucure['resource']`, not a copy. So when you assign `temp_dict['resource']['id']` you're modifying the same dictionary each time.

You could make a deep copy of `JSONStructure` each time through the loop.

```
import copy

    def Obs(self, ObsData):
      JSONStructure = json.load(some json structure)
      for key in ObsData.keys():
         if 'Observation' in key:
             ObsData = ObsData[key]
             new_dict = copy.deepcopy(JSONStructure)
             new_dict['fullUrl'] = ObsData['fullUrl']
             new_dict['resource']['id'] = ObsData['ObsId']
             self.JSONOutput.append(new_dict)
```

or you could just copy `resource`

```
    def Obs(self, ObsData):
      JSONStructure = json.load(some json structure)
      for key in ObsData.keys():
         if 'Observation' in key:
             ObsData = ObsData[key]
             new_dict = JSONStructure.copy()
             new_dict['fullUrl'] = ObsData['fullUrl']
             new_dict['resource'] = new_dict['resource'].copy()
             new_dict['resource']['id'] = ObsData['ObsId']
             self.JSONOutput.append(new_dict)
```

There's no need to make the second copy in `temp_dict`. And calling `dict.copy()` is a simpler way to make a copy than creating a new dictionary and calling `update()`.